# Is it possible to query field name by it's value in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

my document is like this:

```
{
    fruits:{
       apple:[{shop:shop_1},{shop:shop_2}],
       peach:[{shop:shop_1},{shop:shop_2}]
   }
}
```

how can I query the document, by shop_2, and then return ['apple','peach'] ?

or I have to do it in my programming language?

the raw file can be imported to mongo:

```
{"fruits":{"apple":[{"shop":"shop_1"},{"shop":"shop_2"}],"peach":[{"shop":"shop_1"},{"shop":"shop_2"}]}}
```

Comment: You can do it in Mongo, is `fruits` an array or an object?

Comment: @TomSlabbaert, fruits here is an object. thanks. I stored a dictionary to here directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [$objectToArray](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/) and iterate over the array to filter out the matched keys:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "fruits": {
        $map: {
          input: {
            $filter: {
              input: {
                "$objectToArray": "$fruits"
              },
              as: "datum",
              cond: {
                "$setIsSubset": [
                  [
                    "shop_2"
                  ],
                  {
                    "$map": {
                      "input": "$$datum.v",
                      "as": "shop",
                      "in": "$$shop.shop"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          as: "fruit",
          in: "$$fruit.k"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/4EOFkajQKHQ)

Comment: thanks.  do u think it's a good idea to store the dictionary directly into mongodb, according to your experience? or we'd better convert dictionary into array before saving?

Comment: You know best what you're going to be querying most. both structure has advantages and disadvantages. for querying an exact fruit like `'fruits.apple.shop': 'shop_2'` the current structure is better. but for querying similar to what we just an array is better. at the end of the day you should use whatever works best for you.